# How to run PHP in WAMP as an Administrator

Tags: php, windows, exec, wamp

I want to run PHP (5.2.5) on WAMP as the administrator user on Windows 8.  Currently when I run exec("whoami") it returns "nt authority/system".  I want it to run as the Administrator (or more precisely "aaron-desk/administrator") so that I have the correct permissions to run a command line program (TileMill).

I have tried running WAMP as the administrator, but PHP still runs exec() under the system username.

I have also tried setting up services.msc to run the wampapache and wampmysqld services as Administrator (instead of Local System), but when I do this they fail to run.  There is a login error.  I have an empty Administrator password but it does not work for these services when I apply it in services.msc.

I am running Windows 8 Pro as the administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives instructions how to do it in French.  You download and install setacl.  And then run:

```
setacl -on "wampapache" -ot srv -ace "n:Username;p:start_stop,read" -actn ace 
setacl -on "wampmysqld" -ot srv -ace "n:Username;p:start_stop,read" -actn ace
```

[WampServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?1,113644,113725#msg-113725)